# CKEDITOR.replace() is hiding the textarea that I want converted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using Javascript to create a textarea that I want to be a ckeditor. My code is something like

```
var html = '<textarea name="text"></textarea>';
$('#mydiv').append(html);  
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');  
// Could be more than one textarea   
for (i = 0; i<textareas.lenght; i++) {  
    var textarea = textareas[i];  
    CKEDITOR.replace(textarea.name); 
}
```

When I run this code and check the output the textarea is hidden. Inspecting it in firebug I'm getting a style="visibilty:hidden". However removing this just gives me a textarea and not a ckeditor. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve it.

Putting it as a div worked but the examples all seemed to be in textareas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hiding is correct. Because the `<textarea/>` has no wysiwyg support. The `.replace()` method replaces the `<textarea/>` with it's wysiwyg Editor. That's why it's hidden.

> `CKEDITOR.replace(elementOrIdOrName, config)`
>   **Replaces** a  or a DOM element (DIV) with a CKEditor instance. [Source](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html)

As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html) you don't need to append the `<textarea/>`, instead you could use your div directly:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('mydiv')
```

Comment: Thanks but the div will have other content that I don't want replaced. If I wrap the textarea in a div and run replace on that will that work?

Comment: Just to explain further html is not just the textarea. I also have other content being added.

Comment: I don't know if it will work if you wrap the textarea in another div.

Comment: Accepting this because the suggestion to convert a div instead of a text area was what I was doing wrong.